# Style text with HTML tags

Tags: php, html, html-entities

I have a string saved in a database as `<b>hello</b>`

When I get the string from the database using a query, the text isn't bold (which should be caused by the `<b>` tags). Instead, it simply displays as 'hello'.

How can I apply the html tags to the text ?

```
<?php
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
$stmt->execute();
$text = $row['text'];
echo $text;
?>
```

I have tried using `htmlentities` as well as `html_entity_decode`, but the result is the same.

I'm unable to use html tags in the output (`$text = "<b>" . $row['text'] . "</b>";`) as I'm getting multiple strings from the database, each with different html tags.

Comment: If you're not too far in this project, I wouldn't allow html tags but rather using them in the output only. I.e.: `$text = "<b>" . $row['text'] . "</b>";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I had thought about that, but I'm getting multiple strings from the database, all with different html tags (some use `<i>`, some use `<b>`, some use `<a>` e.g)

Comment: That's a shame. Well, what you posted now won't show you the output, you  need to loop over those results if you're not already doing that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I thought it would be easier to post a "simplified" version of the code _(rather than including the loop and more complicated things)_ to make the question easier to understand. I will update my post with the information from my previous comment.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['text']))` ought to work. Try that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Unfortunately no luck... it still displays as 'hello' without the text being bold.

Comment: I have a feeling that `prepare()` might be causing this. Try `query()` instead and get rid of the `$stmt->execute();`. If you're using a prepared statement but not showing us, then that could be it also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still no luck - as you suggested, I updated the line of code to `$stmt = $con->query("SELECT * FROM posts");` and removed `$stmt->execute();`, but there seems to be no change.

Comment: what does `var_dump($text);` produce?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It displays `NULL`

Comment: your query may have failed then, seems like it. There's nothing in there. You need to update your question with the real code you're using. Commenting back and forth is reaching the point of the discussion button showing *lol* check for errors with the MySQL API error checking method you're using. I'm out of ideas now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hang on, I realized I made a simple syntax error when I updated the code with `var_dump($text);`. Rather than `NULL`, it displays `string(2) "hello"`

Comment: btw, have you tried it without those additional functions?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good idea, I hadn't. It still displays `string(2) "hello"` though

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hi Fred, just to let you know that I tried `htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['text']))` again and out of the blue, it strangely worked.

Comment: which is what I suggested earlier *lol*

Comment: @Fred-ii- If you post an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: I'm glad to see this one was solved, *cheers!* Ok, now I can go do my grocery shopping ;-) *au revoir!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *@Fred-ii- Hi Fred, just to let you know that I tried htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['text'])) again and out of the blue, it strangely worked. – The Codese*

As stated in comments:

```
htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['text']))
```

is what should have been used.